# Does ArangoDB java driver provides API for GEO_INTERSECTS

Tags: arangodb

For library arangodb-spring-data, version 3.2.3, is there any possibility to query for GEO_INTERSECTS functionality using the java api provided by the driver?

Currently I am using an AQL query in my code:

```
LET areaLiteral = GEO_POLYGON(...)
FOR doc IN MyDocuments
FILTER GEO_INTERSECTS(areaLiteral, doc.geometry)
LIMIT 5 RETURN doc
```

So far in the official documentation couldn't find anything related to `GEO_INTERSECTS`, also in this example: https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data-demo#geospatial-queries

I have checked the source code of the driver, but didn't find anything related to keyword "`INTERSECTS`" which would construct this query behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not yet supported, the only supported geospatial queries are Near and Within:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/integrations/spring-data-arangodb/reference-version-4/repositories/queries/derived-queries/#geospatial-queries